# Insert data from textbox to database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, textbox

I used model-first approach to make a database. I have a table Person with properties Name and Surname.
I also have a window with two textboxes and a button "Save".
So I want to type something into these textboxes and to save it to database by clicking the button.
As it is not the main window, I transfer some parameters as can be seen

```
<TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock"  Text="EnterName" Width="82" Height="15" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="NameBox" Width="193" Height="32" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="30"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="NicknameBlock"  Text="Enter Surname" Width="82" Height="15" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="67"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="SurnameBox" Width="193" Height="32" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="87"></TextBox>
<Button Name="SaveButton" Click="SaveButton_OnClick" Content="Save" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="176" Height="30" Width="64"></Button>
```

C#:

```
public partial class RegistrationPage : Window
{
    Model1Container db2 = new Model1Container();
    private MainWindow mv = new MainWindow();

    public RegistrationPage(Model1Container d, MainWindow m)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        db2 = d;
        mv = m;
    }

    private void SaveButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I know how to fill it manually in code - I should write like this:

```
Person per = new Person();
per.Name = "Sam";
per.Surname = "Smith";
db2.PersonSet.Add(per);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But I don't know how to make it be inserted from typing in textbox

Comment: Please add more details, like your model first datacontext class etc. What did you try? What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Person per = new Person();
per.Name = NameBox.Text;
per.Surname = SurnameBox.Text;
db2.PersonSet.Add(per);
db.SaveChanges();
```